# svn slow performance while browsing repo

Tags: linux, svn

I noticed a slow authentication and browsing on my svn repo.  What can I do from the backend to troubleshoot?  This is CentOS linux with svn 1.6.9 with fsfs DB.

Comment: What method are you using the serve the repo?

Answer (score 0):

Check where is the bottleneck: CPU, Disk I/O, netowrk, CPU in kernel mode, Interrupts, paging I/O.

For your investigation you can use: `top` and `dstat`.

Next step is to profile the application, the network, disk. Use `strace -cp <SVN_server_PID>`, `netperf`, `iometer`/`bonnie++`.